# how to create group email with CDO Using VB6

Tags: vb6

How can I send an email to a group of recipients with CDO? I'm using VB6.

Comment: @Sathya - [CDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdo) Seems it has something to do with old Exchange servers

Comment: CDO was a simple COM object for sending SMTP email in the days before .NET.

Answer (score 4):

You can list multiple recipients on the .To line by separating them with ";", for example:

```
Set m = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
m.Subject="subject..."
m.From="sender@example.com"
m.To="some@email.com;other@email.com;third@email.com"
m.TextBody="Message"
m.Send
```

Comment: Be very, very careful here. If you're using CDOSYS (as the `CDO.Message` implies): *> Note   **Multiple addressees for a message are separated with commas (as opposed to semicolons**, which are used with Messaging Application Programming Interface (MAPI) clients such as Microsoft® Outlook®).* => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527025(v=exchg.10).aspx

Answer (score -1):

This works in Office 97 and whatever Exchange we had back then:

```
    Dim oOApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim newMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set oOApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set newMail = oOApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 With newMail
  .Display
  .Body = whatever
  .Subject = whatever
  .Attachments.Add whatever
  .Recipients.Add (whomever)
  .Send
 End With
 Set newMail = Nothing
 Set oOApp = Nothing
```