# How to send email to a distribution list with vbScript in an asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm very new to vbscript but here's what I have so far, Doesn't seem to be working though:

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
Sub Senmail()
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objOutlookMsg As Object
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
With objOutlookMsg
   .To = "eric@gmail.com"
   .Cc = "name@email.com"
   .Subject = "Hello World (one more time)..."
   .Body = "This is the body of message"
   .HTMLBody = "HTML version of message"
   .Send 
End With
Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
</script>
```

Any input would be appreciated! Or any other ways I could send an email is my asp....

Comment: have you tried [CDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412129/how-to-create-group-email-with-cdo-using-vb6/4433233#4433233) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using CDO / SMTP

```
Sub SendMail()
    Set objMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set objConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    Set objFields = objConfig.Fields
    With objFields
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "YourSMTPServer"
        .Update
    End With

    With objMsg
        Set.Configuration = objConfig
        .To = "eric@gmail.com"
        .CC = "name@gmail.com"      
        .From = "you@gmail.com"
        .Subject =  "Hello World"
        .HTMLBody = "This is the body of message"
        .Fields.Update
        .Send
    End with

    Set objMsg = Nothing
    Set objConfig = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, remove the `As Object` from your `Dim` statements. In VBScript, you can't declare variables `As` any particular data type. Everything's a variant.

```
Dim objOutlook 
Dim objOutlookMsg
```

If you want more help, then you may want to tell us something more specific about your problem than "Doesn't seem to be working" e.g. what error or wrong behaviour you are getting.