# VBScript to send email without running Outlook

Tags: vbscript, sendmail, outlook-2007

I have written an automated test that runs each night, and I would like to email the results each night once the test is finished.

In order to do this I attempted to put the following at the end of my batchfile:

```
Set MyApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MyItem = MyApp.CreateItem(0)
With MyItem
    .To = "a@a.com"
    .Subject = "Subject"
    .ReadReceiptRequested = False
    .HTMLBody = "resport"
End With
MyItem.Send
```

However, this is causing the email to not send because my Outlook is not open, as the test is run in the background, and I have no access to the UI.

Is there anyway to send this email without actually running outlook on the machine.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588621/how-to-send-email-to-a-distribution-list-with-vbscript-in-an-asp

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can send email without Outlook in VBScript using the **CDO.Message** object.  You will need to know the address of your SMTP server to use this:

```
Set MyEmail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")

MyEmail.Subject="Subject"
MyEmail.From="name@domain.com"
MyEmail.To="a@a.com"
MyEmail.TextBody="Testing one two three."

MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2

'SMTP Server
MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="smtp.server.com"

'SMTP Port
MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 

MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
MyEmail.Send

set MyEmail=nothing
```

If your SMTP server requires a username and password then paste these lines in above the `MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update` line:

```
'SMTP Auth (For Windows Auth set this to 2)
MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate")=1
'Username
MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")="username" 
'Password
MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")="password"
```

More information on using CDO to send email with VBScript can be found on the link below:
http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps a ton!  I requested the name of the server and should hopefully have it by Monday.  Then I'll select this as the accepted answer.

Comment: What if I want username and machine name to be included in mail like `userxyz logged in to machinexyz`. Actually I have Windows 7 client on which I want to track logins by sending mails. So I will be calling this code as login event task. I have Windows Server 2008 which manages AD. So where should I configure [this](http://superuser.com/questions/660703/getting-mail-on-windows-logon-with-username-of-logged-in-user) rule - on win 7 client or win server. Will that make any difference? Also is it possible to achieve this using `vbs`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Blat or any other self contained SMTP mailer. Blat is a fairly full featured SMTP client that runs from command line

[Blat is here](http://www.blat.net/)

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you can send emails from other services like private email**

```
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
 objMessage.Subject = "Wooow" 
 objMessage.From = "shubham@yourfrom.com" 
 objMessage.To = "info@idkblogs.com" 
 objMessage.TextBody = "You are awesome"
 Set objConfig = objMessage.Configuration
 objConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
 objConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "serverXXXXXX.web-hosting.com"
 objConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
 objConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "shubham@yourfrom.com"
 objConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "YOUR_PASSWORD_XXXX"
 'Server port (typically 25)
 objConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 4XX
 objConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = true
 objConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
 objConfig.Fields.Update
 objMessage.Send
```

I tested it, it's working.