# How Can I attach a file to an email using mailto from Win Console?

Tags: windows, email, cmd, mailto

I've this problem: when I try to do this from my Win Console:

start "" "mailto:example@rat.it?subject=subject&body=body "

everything works fine!

But I'm not able to attach a file to the email adding:

&attachment="path/myfile.txt"

How Can I do? Can anyone help me?

Comment: You cannot use mailto: to to send local files, call a vbscript instead; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041938/vbscript-to-send-email-without-running-outlook

Comment: This option was removed from email client programs a long time ago.  Heavily abused by malware.  You can ask at superuser.com, hard to imagine they'll recommend one.