# Quit Outlook object AFTER email is sent

Tags: vbscript, outlook.application

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Option Explicit

Call OpenOutlook()

Function OpenOutlook()
    Dim ObjShell

    Set ObjShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    ObjShell.Run("Outlook.exe")

    Call SendEmail()

    'I tried closing from here but this didn't work either
    'ObjShell.Quit
End Function

Function SendEmail()
    'Declaring variables used through out this function
    Dim ObjOutlook
    Dim objMail

    Set ObjOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'CreateItem(0) opens a New Email window...MailItem
    set objMail = ObjOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    objMail.Display 

    'MailItem Options
    objMail.to = "test@mail.com.com"    
    'objMail.cc = "test2@mail.com"
    objMail.Subject = "Did it work!?"
    objMail.Body = "If you got this email, my VBs test worked!"
    'objMail.Attachments.Add("C:\Attachment\abc.jpg")
    objMail.Send

    'This didn't work either
    'If objMail.Sent = True Then 
    'ObjOutlook.Quit
    'End If

    'Quit closes Outlook like I want but it doesn't wait for the email to send 
    'ObjOutlook.Quit
End Function
```

What I'm trying to automate using VBScript:

1. Open Outlook
2. Send an email
3. Wait for email to send (Outbox to finish sending)
4. Close Outlook AFTER the email has been sent

Where I'm stuck:

1. First of all, I was having trouble opening Outlook. Below is the code that I used to create an Outlook Object:

   ```
   Set ObjOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   'CreateItem(0) opens a New Email window...MailItem
   set objMail = ObjOutlook.CreateItem(0)
   objMail.Display
   ```

   What I did (Not even sure if this is the right way to do it):

   ```
   Set ObjShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   ObjShell.Run("Outlook.exe")
   ```

   Why can't I just do `ObjShell.Quit` after I call the `SendEmail()` Function? Using `.Quit` gives me an error.
2. I just want to close the Outlook application once the email has been sent and I can't figure out how.

Comment: Do you need to use Outlook? Most VBScripters use the CDO library to send e-mail. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041938/vbscript-to-send-email-without-running-outlook).

Answer (score 1):

`MailItem` has a [`Sent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff868242.aspx) property that indicates when the message has been sent. Try this:

```
...
objMail.Send

Do Until objMail.Sent
    WScript.Sleep 500
Loop

' Safe to close...
ObjOutlook.Quit
```

Comment: This will never work. The message becomes sent after it is sent and moved to the Sent Items folder. It will be a different message from the one you sent. More than that, touching a message in any way after calling Send will abort the submission process.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Really? You can't check a `MailItem`'s properties while it's in the process of sending? Seems odd. Guess that rules out my next idea... checking to see if the `MailItem`'s parent folder is the "Sent" folder.

Comment: Yes, after calling Send the only allowed operation on the MialItem object is releasing it - the message now belongs to the spooler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SendMail()
  Dim outobj, mailobj
  Set outobj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  Set mailobj = outobj.CreateItem(0)

    With mailobj
        .To = "user@test.com"
        .Subject = "Testmail"
        .Body = "If you got this email, my VBs test worked!"
        .Send
    End With

    'Clear the memory
    Set outobj = Nothing
    Set mailobj = Nothing
End Sub
SendMail()
Msgbox("Done")
```

Comment: Thank you all! @Bk, I tried your code and it worked perfectly! Can you tell me what your last chunk of code is doing?

Comment: @Edrei Of course. The line "SendMail()" calls the subroutine " Sub Sendmail()" (the second line). After the code is processed between "Sub Sendmail()" and "End Sub" (from top to down) it goes back again to the second-to-last line "SendMail()". The next line creates a Messagebox with the text "Done".

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what if it was the ***user*** who opened Outlook? I don't think any user will appreciate your code closing Outlook. You might want to check that both `Application.Explorers.Count` and `Application.Inspectors.Count` are zero before closing Outlook. Newest version of Outlook will automatically exist if there are no open explorers or inspectors even if you hold a reference to an Outlook object - that was done to guard ageist misbehaving apps that leaked references. To prevent Outlook from closing, hodl a reference to an Explorer object t(even if you do not show it) - call Namespace.getDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox), then hold a reference to the object returned by MAPIFolder.GetExplorer .

Secondly, after calling Send, use Namespace,SyncObjects collection to retrieve the very first SyncObject. Hook up the SyncObject.SyncEnd event and call SyncObject.Start. When SyncEnd event fires, you will be all done. But I don't think you can work with events in VB script...