# Cant send email using VBA

Tags: vba, email, outlook, sendkeys

I am creating a tool that will automatically dispatch emails out.

I have started to build it using very simple code as below:

```
Set outlookobj = New Outlook.Application
Set mitem = outlookobj.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With mitem
.To = "A_Valid_Email@email.com"
.Subject = "TEST"
.Body = "test"
.Display
.Send

End With
End Sub
```

However the company I work for seem to have locked down .send.  The email will create fine but will not send.  Can anyone think of a way around this?  I have considered using .sendkeys "^{ENTER}" however I know they are not a good way to doing things.

Thank you in advance
Matt

Comment: "seem to have locked down .send" - do you mean you get a security prompt?

Comment: No it runs the code but doesn't do anything.  Apparently when the company started using Office 2010 they locked down some features of VBA and this is one of them.

Comment: Is Outlook running at the time your code is executed?

Comment: It is accepted within the business that this bit of code has been disabled

Comment: If you call Save instead of Send, do you see the saved message in the Drafts folder? There is no way to "disable" some OOM functions.

Comment: Save works fine, as does .display etc  I am working on trying to get it disabled however in a company this size that will be a long drawn process.

Comment: Try Using SelfCert to Create a Digital Certificate for VBA Projects and sign to it. then run your code again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041938/vbscript-to-send-email-without-running-outlook Answer given by michaelx386 worked perfect for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm referring to this thread: [Excel VBA sending mail using Outlook - Send method fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883088/excel-vba-sending-mail-using-outlook-send-method-fails) where the solution was the following:

"Change .Send to .Display and put SendKeys "^{ENTER}" before the With mitem line."

You can at least try it, maybe it works for you as well. :)

Comment: Hi, I've played with sendkeys earlier today, it either works fine or highlights the from column, i cant see any logical reason which one it goes for.  I've been trying to find a way to make vba find the word "Send" and click.  No joy so far

Comment: Worth a try. I hope you'll find a solution. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with not using Outlook, you can use CDO to send emails.  I'm not sure if this will get around your security issue, but it might be worth a try.  Here is an example.

```
Sub CDO_Mail_Small_Text(ByVal RecipientList As String, ByVal From As String, _
        ByVal Subject As String, ByVal Body As String, ByVal Attachment As String, _
        ByVal cc As String)
    Dim iMsg As Message
    Dim iConf As Configuration
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim Flds As Variant

    Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields
    With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") _
                       = "webmail.zimmer.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Update
    End With

    With iMsg
        Set .Configuration = iConf
        .To = RecipientList
        .cc = cc
        .From = From
        .Subject = Subject
        .HTMLBody = Body
    End With

    If Attachment <> "" Then
        iMsg.AddAttachment Attachment
    End If

    iMsg.Send

End Sub
```

By the way, this has the additional advantage of letting you spoof the sender and make it appear as though it came from someone else.  I don't know if that's handy or not, but just FYI.

Comment: Hi Hambone,  I looked into doing something like this, however i am must use Outlook for security purposes.  Im beginning to see a loop here.  Thanks for the response though  - Matt

Comment: I hear ya...  keep it in mind if the powers that be get desperate.  Good luck.