# Implement xp_sendmail in VBS

Tags: sql-server, vbscript

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=mydb;Data Source=myserver" 
Set dbconn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbconn.Open ConnectionString

DIM cmd
SET cmd = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
SET cmd.ActiveConnection = Connection

cmd.CommandText = "xp_sendmail"
cmd.CommandType = 4 

cmd.Parameters("@Recipients") = "me@me.com" 
cmd.Parameters("@Subject") = "Test" 
cmd.Parameters("@message") = "Test" 

cmd.Execute
```

My script gives me an error:

> Object required: 'server'

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try removing "server." since you are running the script via WScript/CScript.

Comment: Hi, It gave an error: Object Required: ActiveConnection

Comment: Perhaps you intend `dbconn` instead of `Connection`.

Comment: Hi, you're correct but it still gives me an error in this line cmd.Parameters("@Recipients") = "me@me.com"
item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal

Comment: I addition to the parameter documentation Ekkehard.Horner provided, I suggest you send the mail directly from your script instead of using a database call.  The deprecated `xp_sendmail` has been removed in modern SQL Server versions in favor of `sp_send_dbmail`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041938/vbscript-to-send-email-without-running-outlook for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms675869(v=vs.85).aspx) to learn why and how to .Append parameters.

Comment: Hi @Ekkehard , I've read the documentation but when I used this

    cmd.parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Recipients", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "me@me.com")


It gave me error 800A0BB9 arguments are of the wrong type.....

Comment: Did you define the ad* constants?