# Error on calling xp_sendmail in vbs

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, vbscript

Hi I have my vbs script below to send email by executing xp_sendmail.

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=master;Data Source=myserver" 
Set dbconn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbconn.Open ConnectionString

DIM cmd
SET cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
SET cmd.ActiveConnection = dbconn
cmd.CommandText = "xp_sendmail"
cmd.CommandType = 4  'adCmdStoredProc
Dim email = "me@me.com"
Dim subj = "test"
Dim msg = "message"

cmd.Parameters("@Recipients") = email
cmd.Parameters("@Subject") = subj
cmd.Parameters("@message") = msg 
cmd.Execute
```

This gives an error on the line:

```
Dim email = "me@me.com"
```

> Error: Expected end of element. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you also get the error if you remove 'adCmdStoredProc?

Comment: `Dim email` and on another line `email="me@me.com"`

Comment: Hi @noodles, I tried your suggestion but now it gives me an error: Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.
line: cmd.Parameters("@Recipients") = email

Comment: @JeroenHeier yes I still have error.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38581757/603855

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement xp\_sendmail in VBS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579959/implement-xp-sendmail-in-vbs)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
Dim email = "me@me.com"
Dim subj = "test"
Dim msg = "message"

cmd.Parameters("@Recipients") = email
cmd.Parameters("@Subject") = subj
cmd.Parameters("@message") = msg
```

To this:

```
cmd.parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Recipients", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "me@me.com") 
cmd.parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Subject", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "test") 
cmd.parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Message", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "message")
```

In another words you need to append parameters and than execute command. Info about `CreateParameter` is [here](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ado/8528) about `Append` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms675869(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Hi @gofr1. I tried your solution but now it gives me an error: Arguments are of wrong type etc.. 800A0BB9, ADODB.Command

Comment: Try adVarWChar, it is similar to nvarchar SQL server datatype.