# createobject outlook.application fails when taskmanager cscript launches .vbs file

Tags: vba

I send an email in vba which works successfully but fails when I have task manager launch a cscript to run that same macro.  Does anyone know how to fix?

```
Dim aOutlook As Object
Dim aEmail As Object
Dim stringEmail As String
Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

the error message is on CreateObject and states Server Error.  But again it works when I run the macro, but fails if task manager launches cscript .vbs file, which launches actual macro.

[image: taskmanager]

Comment: I presume you mean Task *Scheduler*? - Automating Office in this way - in an unattended, non-interactive context (particularly under the system account which is the default for scheduled tasks) - is [not supported at all](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2). Instead you could try something like [CDO Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041938/vbscript-to-send-email-without-running-outlook)

Comment: sorry, yes I meant scheduler.  I will check out cdo objects... thank you!